# Google script to getValue AND keep formatting (not just text)

Tags: google-sheets, gmail, google-apps-script

I'm writing a gmailApp script that looks at a spreadsheet and will send some emails out based on a sheet of names and emails. I'm trying to make it as user-friendly as possible. I'm aware I can use the option parameter and use htmlBody to send an email with formatting but I'd prefer the end-user not to have to enter the script to update the body if they want a link or to bold something.

I have a cell for the email body like this but can't seem to find the function to capture the formatting.

> Dear {{name}},
>
> Something **something** test. [Link](https://google.com)
>
> Thanks

And when I use getValue or getDisplayValue it just returns

> Dear {{name}}, Something something test. Link Thanks

No new lines, no links or formatting, etc. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to convert a the rich text content from a cell into HTML.

One way is the following

1. First the code have to get a `RichTextValue` object
2. then get the "runs"
3. then get the content and formatting of each run
4. then convert the convert that into HTML

Another way is the following:

1. First the code have to export the spreadsheet to HTML
2. then get the cell content

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value

Comment: Thanks @Rubén. I think this is going to have to be a larger project when I have time but I was able to get runs, I just don't know how to account for all the combinations someone would use. As a temp solution, I am just writing good 'ol HTML directly into the cell and then using .htmlBody with SendMail which works great.